# Set color for only half border (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm aware of multiple possibilities to set the color of a border to change only parts of it, but in my slightly more complex example I'm struggling to get the desired result.

Desired result:
[image]

My attempt so far:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 1rem/1.4 sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
  min-height: 35vh; /* At least the full height of the viewport */
  margin: 0;
}


/* Timeline Container */

.timeline {
  --m: 3rem;
  /* margin */
  --w: 20px;
  /* Snake width (thickness) */
  --r: 3rem;
  /* Radius */
  display: flex;
  padding: 5rem;
  gap: var(--m);
  width:90%;
}

/* Card container */

.card {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 0px;
  border: var(--b) solid #000;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  h3 {
    padding: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Snake line */
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(var(--m) / -2 - var(--w) / 2);
    width: calc(100% + var(--m) + var(--w));
    height: calc(50% + var(--m) / 2 + var(--w));
    border: var(--w) solid orange;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  &:first-child::before {
    clip-path: polygon(var(--r) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, var(--r) 100%);
  }
  &:last-child::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - var(--r)) 0, calc(100% - var(--r)) 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  &:nth-child(odd)::before {
    top: calc(var(--m) / -2 - var(--w));
    border-radius: var(--r) var(--r) 0 0;
    border-bottom: transparent;
  }
  &:nth-child(even)::before {
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 0 var(--r) var(--r);
    border-top: transparent;
  }
  /* Pills */
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    content: attr(data-desc);
    background: #1B564B;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: var(--r);
    text-align: center;
  }
  &:nth-child(odd)::after {
    top: 0%;
    translate: -50% calc(-50% - var(--m) / 2 - var(--w) / 2);
  }
  &:nth-child(even)::after {
    top: 100%;
    translate: -50% calc(-50% + var(--m) / 2 + var(--w) / 2);
  }
}

/* Target the 'snake' before the card after the 'Now' pill */
.card[data-desc="Now"] + .card::before {
  border-color: red; /* Change the border color for the 'snake' */
}

/* Since the 'snake' is created using the border property, we have to adjust the border-color for the specific sides to change its color */
.card[data-desc="Now"] + .card:nth-child(odd)::before {
  border-top-color: red; /* New color for the top part of the 'snake' */
  border-bottom-color: transparent; /* Keep the bottom part of the 'snake' transparent */
}

.card[data-desc="Now"] + .card:nth-child(even)::before {
  border-bottom-color: red; /* New color for the bottom part of the 'snake' */
  border-top-color: transparent; /* Keep the top part of the 'snake' transparent */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="timeline_stylescopy.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="timeline">
        <div class="card" data-desc="Summer 2022">
            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="title">Shaping the concept</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-desc="Spring 2023">
            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="title">Sanity check</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-desc="Summer 2023">
            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="title">The leap of faith</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-desc="Now">
            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="title">Building in progress</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-desc="Spring 2024">
            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="title">It's launch time, baby!</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to target the pseudo-element `::before` that creates the "snake" line for the card that comes after the "Now" pill and change its color. The "Now" pill is associated with the card with the `data-desc="Now"`, so I tried to select the `::before` pseudo-element of the card that comes immediately after this card. But somehow I'm either changing the snake either too late (like in the code snippet) or too soon if I pick the previous card.

Comment: With your current attempt, your `::before` pseudo elements create either the bottom `⎵` "bracket", or the top `⎴` one. But you want to color "half" of such a bracket differently, and that obviously can't work this way.

Comment: Your pseudo elements would have to take the shapes `_|‾` and `‾|_` respectively, so that you can color the correct "section".

Comment: @CBroe so it would be to change the polygon shape you reckon?

Comment: That, and probably the _positioning_ of the pseudo elements accordingly as well then.